# Number of outcomes, if having known the distinct numbers and number of choices

Tags: probability, statistics

This question came to me, when I was solving another relavent question in my class:

We have $N$ distinct numbers, say $P(X=i)=1/N$, with $i=1,...,N$. We choose $n$ (known) numbers from them (with replacement). But we do not know what we have got excatly for each time. What we only know is the distinct numbers in our choices $(X_{1}^{*},...,X_{r}^{*})$ (**Update: No order in them, which means $X_{i}^{*}$ could happen at any time within $n$ tries**), and the size of this set $r$. The question is to calculate the number of outcomes given known $(X_{1}^{*},...,X_{r}^{*})$ and $r$. Or the following probability:

$$P(X_{1}^{*},...,X_{r}^{*},r,n|N)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to know the probability of obtaining $r$ *specific* distinct numbers by unbiased selection of $n$ from $N$ numbers with replacement.

The [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $\begin{Bmatrix}n\\r\end{Bmatrix}$ counts the ways to partition $n$ labelled items into $r$ *non-empty* unlabelled subsets.

$$P=\dfrac{\begin{Bmatrix}n\\r\end{Bmatrix}r!}{n^N}$$

Comment: Wikipedia says: The Stirling numbers of the second kind, count the number of ways to partition a set of n **LABELLED** objects into k nonempty unlabeled subsets.

Answer (score 1):

So we know that we sampled $n$ times, and we know the numbers that came up, but not their respective multiplicities.

Arrange the numbers we got in order, and let their multiplicities be $x_1$ to $x_r$ respectively. Then $x_1+\cdots +x_r=n$. By Stars and Bars the number of possibilities is $\binom{n+r-1}{n}$.

Note that these possibilities are not all equally likely.

*Added*: For order matters, we are counting the number of **onto** functions from the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to the set $\{1,2,\dots,r\}$. For information on how to count this, please see Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind. There is not a closed form, but there are useful recurrences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought of this too. Sorry I didn't clarify myself enough. There is no order in $X_{1}^{*},...,X_{r}^{*}$. So, if I let $N=3$, $r=2$, $n=3$ and the distinct numbers be $(1,2)$. I would have $(1,2,1;1,2,2;1,1,2;2,1,1;2,1,2;2,2,1)$. The number of possible outcomes would be 6 not 4.

Comment: @ZhengWang: I will try to look at the "order matters" problem. There will I think not be a closed form, unless you count Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind as closed form.